# glib.GError: No D-BUS daemon running

Tags: dbus

When trying to run meld on Ubuntu Desktop 13.04, I get the following error:

```
$ meld

(meld:1509): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-EQeHnPP7h5: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
glib.GError: No D-BUS daemon running
```

I am running as a non-root user, with a X11 forwarding through PuTTY/SSH to Xming.

Answer (score 24):

[This bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=685164) pointed me to two ways to fix it, of which I used:

```
eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
```

Comment: Just tried and it works on 14.04

Comment: I still get many GConf warnings (failed to connect), but not the same reason (was "Connection refused", it's now "Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken." Emacs now starts reasonably fast in my `ssh -X` session, at least.

Comment: you saved my day :)

Comment: Works on 16.10 as well, but I just run it as `sudo dbus-launch --sh-syntax`